# Holding a value fixed in Window Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table **FruitTable**

```
AsOfDate          Fruit          Delta
12/8/2016     Apple              10
12/7/2016     Apple              -5
12/6/2016     Apple              15
12/4/2016     Apple              30
```

However, it is designed so that 12/4/2016 (yesterday) has the total we hold for that day.

I want to output:

```
Date          Fruit          Cumulative
12/8/2016     Apple          30
12/7/2016     Apple          40
12/6/2016     Apple          35
12/5/2016     Apple          50
```

This is calculated in a sense like:

```
SELECT AsOfDate,
Fruit,
SUM(Delta) OVER (PARTITION BY Fruit ORDER BY AsOfDate DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS CUMULATIVE
FROM FruitTable
```

So 12/6/2016 output is 30 + (-5) + 10 = 35 and 12/7/2016 is 30 + 10 = 40
Output 12/6/2016 = 12/4/2016 + 12/7/2016 + 12/8/2016

Is there a way to specify a specific row in the OVER clause or what would be the best way to approach? I am using SQL SERVER

Thank you

Comment: Can you check if the sample data and the question is connected? For example, compare to your data, and this piece "So 12/6/2016 output is 30 + (-5) + 10 = 35 and 12/7/2016 is 30 + 10 = 40", where does -5 and 10 come from for 12/6/2016?

Comment: i don't understand your logic at all.

Comment: To get previous value, you use `LAG()` but not sure about your logic. How first value is 30 ?

Comment: sorry i edited a bit. So its a running total for every future day + 12/4/2016 (yesterday). does that make sense?

Comment: Ohhh you put the dates in desc order :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (AsOfDate date,Fruit varchar(25),Delta int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2016-12-08','Apple',10),
('2016-12-07','Apple',-5),
('2016-12-06','Apple',15),
('2016-12-04','Apple',30)

Select AsOfDate
      ,Fruit
      ,Delta
      ,Cumulative = Sum(Delta) over (Partition By Fruit Order By AsOfDate Desc) - Delta + First_Value(Delta) over (Partition By Fruit Order By IIF(Delta is null,1,0),AsOfDate)
 From  @YourTable
 Order By 1 Desc
```

Returns

```
AsOfDate    Fruit   Delta   Cumulative
2016-12-08  Apple   10      30
2016-12-07  Apple   -5      40
2016-12-06  Apple   15      35
2016-12-04  Apple   30      50
```

Comment: so I guess the `12-05` was a typo?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  I guess so, I saw that he removed it.

Comment: yes my apologies... what is your First_Value(delta) ?

Comment: @user3697498 Just another window function.  In this case it would be 30

Comment: @JohnCappelletti is there a way to ignore nulls in SQL Server when using First_Value? I only saw documentation for Oracle

Comment: @user3697498 You can change the Order by in the First_Value.  For example First_Value(Delta) over (Partition By Fruit Order By IIF(Delta is null,1,0),AsOfDate) ... this will force null delta down the list